# When I want to create a new flutter project, flutter just returns to the welcome screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have already installed Flutter and Dart plugins in Android Studio. I go through all the stages of creating a Flutter project but when I click on Finish I get the dialog "creating a new flutter project" but after a few seconds the welcome screen keeps showing up and I'm back at square one. Can anyone help, please?

Here's the information of "flutter doctor -v" command:

```
CreateProcessW failed 87
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (4 weeks ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0
    X Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
      See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information


[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.


[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Comment: Try to create the project using the command `flutter create name`, to see if it’s a IDE issue or a flutter one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a problem with Flutter installation. You can try to reinstall it (make sure you get version for your OS).
The second problem is with Android SDK. Installing Android Studio is not enough. Try going through this setup instructions: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install#android-setup.